# Django Generate List of Opposite Models

Tags: python, django

I am trying to develop a program that will determine what plants are beneficial and harmful to other plants. I want it to be able to run through a list of plants and compare and see if one plant's `deters_insects_and_animals` species matches the other plant's `pests` then it adds it to the list in `ally_deter_pests_for(self):`
I'm not really sure how to do that.

```
     class AnimalSpecies(models.Model):
            common_name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
            scientific_name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
        
            genus = Foreign

Key(Genus, null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = "Animal Species"
            verbose_name_plural = "Animal Species"
        def __str__(self):
            return self.common_name
    #___________________________________________________________________________________Begin Species_______________________________________________
    class PlantSpecies(models.Model):
        #________________________Name & Relationships________________________
        common_name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
        species_name = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)
        genus = ForeignKey(Genus, blank = True, null =True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        rotation_family = ForeignKey(RotationFamily, blank = True, null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    
        #________________________Growth & Environment________________________
        annual = BooleanField(null = True, blank = True)
        GROWTH_HABIT_LIST = [
            ("H", "Herb"),
            ("S", "Shrub"),
            ("T", "Tree"),
            ("U", "Succulent"),
            ("G", "Grass"),
            ("F", "Fern"),
            ("V", "Vine")
        ]
        growth_habit = CharField(max_length = 20, blank = True, null = True, choices = GROWTH_HABIT_LIST)
        pruning = TextField(max_length = 1000, null = True, blank = True)
        days_to_germinate = IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        days_to_maturity = IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        zone = IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
    
        SUN_REQUIREMENT_LIST = [
            ("FH", "Full Shade"),
            ("FHPH", "Full Shade-Partial Shade"),
            ("PHFS", "Partial Shade-Full Sun"),
            ("FS", "Full Sun")
        ]
        sun_requirement = CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True, choices = SUN_REQUIREMENT_LIST)
        WATER_REQUIREMENT_LIST = [
            ("M", "Mesic"),
        ]
        water_requirement = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = WATER_REQUIREMENT_LIST)
    
    
        pollinator = ManyToManyField(AnimalSpecies, blank = True, related_name = "pollinators")
        beneficials = ManyToManyField(AnimalSpecies, blank = True, related_name = "beneficials")
        pests = ManyToManyField(AnimalSpecies, blank = True, related_name = "Pests")
    
        deters_insect_and_animals = ManyToManyField(AnimalSpecies, blank = True, related_name = "deters_AnimalSpecies")
        
        #________________________Spacing________________________
        number_per_square_foot = IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        spacing_inches = FloatField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        spread_inches = FloatField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        height = IntegerField(null = True, blank = True, default = 0)
        #________________________Yield________________________
        expected_yield_pounds = FloatField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True, default = 0)
        expected_pound_per_fruit = FloatField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True, default = 0)
        #________________________Description________________________
        COLOR_CHOICES = [
            ("RE", "Red"),
            ("OR", "Orange"),
            ("YE", "Yellow"),
            ("LGR", "Light Green"),
            ("GR", "Green"),
            ("DGR", "Dark Green"),
            ("BL", "Blue"),
            ("PU", "Purple"),
            ("PI", "Pink"),
            ("WH", "White")
        ]
       
        
        foliage_color = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = COLOR_CHOICES)
        flower_color = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = COLOR_CHOICES)
        fruit_color = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = COLOR_CHOICES)
    
        PARTS_CHOICES = [
            ("FLRW", "Fruit, Leaves, Roots, Flowers"),
            ("FLW", "Fruit, Leaves, Flowers"),
            ("FR", "Fruit, Roots, Flowers"),
            ("LR", "Leaves, Roots, Flowers"),
            ("LRW", "Leaves, Roots, Flowers"),
            ("FL", "Fruit, Leaves"),
            ("FR", "Fruit, Roots"),
            ("LR", "Leaves, Roots"),
            ("F", "Fruit"),
            ("L", "Leaves"),
            ("R", "Roots"),
            ("W", "Flowers"),
            ("O", "Other"),
            ("N", "None")
        ]
        edible_parts = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = PARTS_CHOICES)
        toxic_parts = CharField(max_length = 20, null = True, blank = True, choices = PARTS_CHOICES)
        @property
        def improves_growth_and_flavor(self):
            return ManyToManyField(self, blank = True, related_name = "improves_growth")
        
        @property
        def improves_health_and_flavor(self):
            return ManyToManyField(self, blank = True, related_name = "improves_health")
        @property
        def impairs_health_and_growth(self):
            return ManyToManyField(self, blank = True, related_name = "impairs_health")
            
        @property
        def visual_name(self):
            return f"{self.rotation_family.visual_color}{self.common_name}"
        visual_name.fget.short_description = "Name"
        @property
        def scientific_name(self):
            return f"{self.genus.scientific_name} {self.species_name}"
        @property
        def expected_fruit_yield(self):
            try:
                return self.expected_yield_pounds / self.expected_pound_per_fruit
            except:
                return "0"
    
        @property
        def ally_deter_pest_for(self):
            x = []
            y = PlantSpecies.objects.filter(self.pests)
            for i in range(len(self.deters_insect_and_animals)):
                for h in range(len(y)):
                    if self.deters_insect_and_animals[i] == y[h]:
                        x.append(f"{y[h].common_name} | {self.deters_insect_and_animals[i]}")
                    else:
                        pass
            return x
```

For example, it would find that marigolds deter flea beetles, and broccoli is affected by flea beetles. Therefore, marigolds `ally_deter_pest_for(self):`would `x.append(broccoli)`

Right now I get an error

Internal Server Error: /admin/GardenApp/plantspecies/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 575, in get_field
return self.fields_map[field_name]
KeyError: 'ally_deter_pest_for'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 265, in lookup_field
f = _get_non_gfk_field(opts, name)
File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py", line 296, in _get_non_gfk_field
field = opts.get_field(name)
File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 577, in get_field
raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: PlantSpecies has no field named 'ally_deter_pest_for'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 202, in _get_response
> response = response.render()   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py",
> line 105, in render
> self.content = self.rendered_content   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py",
> line 83, in rendered_content
> return template.render(context, self._request)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py",
> line 61, in render
> return self.template.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 170, in render
> return self._render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 150, in render
> return compiled_parent._render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 162, in _render
> return self.nodelist.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 62, in render
> result = block.nodelist.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 938, in render
> bit = node.render_annotated(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 905, in render_annotated
> return self.render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\base.py",
> line 33, in render
> return super().render(context)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py",
> line 214, in render
> _dict = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py",
> line 341, in result_list
> 'results': list(results(cl)),   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py",
> line 317, in results
> yield ResultList(None, items_for_result(cl, res, None))   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py",
> line 308, in **init**
> super().**init**(*items)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templatetags\admin_list.py",
> line 233, in items_for_result
> f, attr, value = lookup_field(field_name, result, cl.model_admin)   File
> "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\utils.py",
> line 276, in lookup_field
> attr = getattr(obj, name)   File "C:\Users\deant\OneDrive\Documents\Django\Aegirsoft_Garden\GardenApp\models.py",
> line 201, in ally_deter_pest_for
> y = PlantSpecies.objects.filter(self.pests)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py",
> line 85, in manager_method
> return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 942, in filter
> return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
> clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
> line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
> self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
> line 1358, in add_q
> clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
> line 1377, in _add_q
> child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(   File "C:\Users\deant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py",
> line 1255, in build_filter
> arg, value = filter_expr TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object [01/Sep/2021 01:51:57] "GET
> /admin/GardenApp/plantspecies/ HTTP/1.1" 500 400341

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get all the related objects.

```
for i in range(len(self.deters_insect_and_animals.all())):
    # further code
```

Reference: [ManyToMany Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: `range(len(…))` is one of the most common anti-patterns in Python.

Comment: @KlausD. For querysets, i agree. But this answer is intended to resolve the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then you should make it a real answer with real information.

Comment: What is an anti-pattern?